# Warning: NAs introduced by coercion when Replacing Number in list of numbers with Quartile Range character

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and have tried to search for similar NA introduced by coercion errors, but in my case I receive this warning when running the following code, despite it seemingly working:

> x<-c(0.0526,  0.1068,  0.0949,  0.0475, -0.3409 ,-0.0274,  0.1607 , 0.0964, -0.0340  ,0.0093,  0.0504,  0.1549  ,0.0386, -0.0557, -0.0754 , 0.0141  ,0.1151 , 0.2173 , 0.1324 ,-0.0574 ,-0.0484,  0.0197, -0.0458 ,-0.0586 ,-0.0137 ,-0.0821 , 0.0877, -0.0668, -0.0871, -0.1810, -0.2832 ,-0.1525,  0.0211 ,-0.1331 ,-0.1719 , 0.1391 , 0.0941, -0.0341, -0.1839  ,0.1012, -0.1970, -0.1037 ,-0.0964, -0.1366 ,-0.0958, -0.1717 , 0.1155 ,-0.0472 , 0.2427 , 0.0191,  0.0476,  0.1306,  0.0712 , 0.1148 ,0.1651, -0.0431, -0.0183, -0.1063,  0.0607,  0.1499, 0.0257, -0.0482, -0.0832 , 0.0487, -0.0318, -0.0488,  -0.1711,  0.1053,  0.1202,  0.0715,  0.1258, -0.0191,  0.0946 , 0.0607  ,0.0826, 0.0613 ,-0.0113)

I am trying to replace the values of x with a character for the quartile range that the number falls into, using the following commands:

```
     quartiles<-quantile(x,na.rm=TRUE)
    (x<-as.list(x))
    (x[x>=quartiles[1] & x<quartiles[2]] <-paste("Quartile 1: ",quartiles[1],"-",quartiles[2],sep=""))
    (x[x>=quartiles[2] & x<quartiles[3]] <-paste("Quartile 2: ",quartiles[2],"-",quartiles[3],sep=""))
    (x[x>=quartiles[3] & x<quartiles[4]] <-paste("Quartile 3: ",quartiles[3],"-",quartiles[4],sep=""))
    (x[x>=quartiles[4] & x<=quartiles[5]]<-paste("Quartile 4: ",quartiles[4],"-",quartiles[5],sep=""))
    x<-unlist(x)
    x
```

The steps where i attempt to select the values in X between quartile numbers (i.e. 1 and 2 for Q1) and replace them with their respective quartile range characters is where i am getting the following warning printouts:

Q1 command: no errors?

Q2 command:

```
There were 38 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Q3 command:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Q4 command:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The warnings are all of the type:

```
1: In x[x >= quartiles[4] & x <= quartiles[5]] <- paste("Quartile 4: ",  ... :
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Nevertheless, it appears that the new x vector contains no NAs anywhere and each value has been replaced with its corresponding Quartile and range.

Before using as.list(x), i tried to do the same process using:

```
quartiles<-quantile(x,na.rm=TRUE)
    (x[x>=quartiles[1] & x<quartiles[2]] <-paste("Quartile 1: ",quartiles[1],"-",quartiles[2],sep=""))
    (x[x>=quartiles[2] & x<quartiles[3]] <-paste("Quartile 2: ",quartiles[2],"-",quartiles[3],sep=""))
    (x[x>=quartiles[3] & x<quartiles[4]] <-paste("Quartile 3: ",quartiles[3],"-",quartiles[4],sep=""))
    (x[x>=quartiles[4] & x<=quartiles[5]]<-paste("Quartile 4: ",quartiles[4],"-",quartiles[5],sep=""))
    x
```

This sort of worked, but all of the values are not replaced correctly, namely the 18 Q2 values that remain unchanged (although one Q2 value is changed (x[22]).

> x
>    [1] "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"
>    [5] "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "-0.0274"                     "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"
>    [9] "-0.034"                      "Quartile 2: -0.0668-0.0141"  "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"
>   [13] "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "-0.0557"                     "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"
>   [17] "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "-0.0574"
>   [21] "-0.0484"                     "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "-0.0458"                     "-0.0586"
>   [25] "-0.0137"                     "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 2: -0.0668-0.0141" 
>   [29] "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668"
>   [33] "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"
>   [37] "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "-0.0341"                     "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"
>   [41] "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668"
>   [45] "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "-0.0472"
>   [49] "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"
>   [53] "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "-0.0431"
>   [57] "-0.0183"                     "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"
>   [61] "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "-0.0482"                     "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"
>   [65] "-0.0318"                     "-0.0488"                     "Quartile 1: -0.3409--0.0668" "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"
>   [69] "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "-0.0191"
>   [73] "Quartile 4: 0.0946-0.2427"   "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"   "Quartile 3: 0.0141-0.0946"
>   [77] "-0.0113"

I figured this had something to do with the class of the whole vector being changed when the first substitution command was executed, hence why i used as.list(x) thinking that a list can hold objects of different classes.

Anyway, any idea what is going on, and is there a better method to try and accomplish this task? i can suppressWarnings() the substitution commands and everything seems to work but I'd really like to improve my abilities and avoid these problems in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can solve this problem easily by not replacing values in x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign characters to numeric variables, which you shouldn't.

Here is a better solution using the `cut` function, which is designed for this:

```
y <- cut(x, quartiles,  include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE)
levels(y) <- paste0("Quartile ", 1:4, ": ", levels(y))

head(y)

#[1] Quartile 3: [0.0141,0.0946)  Quartile 4: [0.0946,0.243]   Quartile 4: [0.0946,0.243]   Quartile 3: [0.0141,0.0946) 
#[5] Quartile 1: [-0.341,-0.0668) Quartile 2: [-0.0668,0.0141)
#Levels: Quartile 1: [-0.341,-0.0668) Quartile 2: [-0.0668,0.0141) Quartile 3: [0.0141,0.0946) Quartile 4: [0.0946,0.243]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Much more concise and avoids all of the issues that were popping up! Ill have to look into how to use the cut function more, thanks a lot!